# lid wel beend maar niet gepresenteerd

Tags: data-import

Ik heb gisteren Nick Poelenjee toegevoegd als lid Den Haag.
Ik zie hem niet terug bij de lidmaatschappen. Als ik hem opnieuw wil aanmelden dan zegt het systeem hem wel te kennen.
Hoe los je dit op

Answer (score 1):

Hoe heb je Nick toegevoegd? Als je de contactkaart in CiviCRM bekijkt dan zie je daar als het goed is een tabje lidmaatschappen staan. Als je daar op klikt dan kan het zijn dat daar een inactief lidmaatschap staat.

Overigens helpt het als je vraag in het engels stelt want dan zijn er meer mensen die je vraag kunnen beantwoorden.